# VSE Voice Over Capability

Tags: video-sequence-editor

New user evaluating Blender here...

For the Video Editor component of Blender, I fail to locate the ability to record a voice over. Does Blender VSE have the ability to capture audio from a microphone directly to the timeline and save the captured audio as a separate WAV file? Kdenlive, Lightworks, and Davinci Resolve have this ability.

If not, are there plans to add this feature in the future?

I am having trouble finding Linux software with this feature. I can't use DR in Linux due to no H.264 codec support and me having a full AMD system (mobo, CPU, GPU), Lightworks records voice over as MXF file and is very unconventional for editing from what I am used to, and Kdenlive I just do not like not to mention its love of crashing. At this time, I am forced to record narration with Audio Recorder, clean up in Audacity, import the file into Flowblade, and manually sync it with video.

I can tell the VSE in Blender is a sub component as modeling is its main function. It's a bit unconventional to do editing like Lightworks but I can grasp its functionality quicker if I stuck with it. But, there is no reason for me to use it over Flowblade if I have to use the same import/manual sync process for narration. I do like that it is FOSS with no restrictions or licensing vs Lightworks.

Answer (score 2):

No, this feature is not in Blender.

It has been suggested here:
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/7cfbbc/
But so far it has only one vote...

However, Shotcut has this feature:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkLgpx2E6CI

EDIT: This add-on can be used: https://github.com/tin2tin/audacity_tools_for_blender

Comment: Thanks! I gave the post another vote for recording a voiceover in Blender. Shotcut I’ve reviewed before. It still requires reimporting the wav aligning it up into the timeline manually. Unfortunately, this has become a tedious task especially since I create multiple videos a week. I have a feature request for this to be added to Flowblade and the developers have already agreed to try and implement it two versions from now. In the interim, while I wait, I’ll be switching back to Windows so I can use Davinci Resolve.